# Mongoose Query: compare two values on same document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I query a Mongo collection using Mongoose to find all the documents that have a specific relation between two of their own properties?

For example, how can I query a `characters` collections to find all those characters that have their `currentHitPoints` value less than their `maximumHitPoints` value? Or all those `projects` that have their `currentPledgedMoney` less than their `pledgeGoal`?

I tried to something like this:

```
mongoose.model('Character')
    .find({
        player: _currentPlayer
    })
    .where('status.currentHitpoints').lt('status.maximumHitpoints')
    .exec(callback)
```

but I am getting errors since the `lt` argument must be a `Number`. The same goes if I use `$.status.maximumHitpoints` (I was hoping Mongoose would be able to resolve it like it does when doing collection operations).

Is this something that can be done within a Query? I would expect so, but can't find out how. Otherwise I can filter the whole collection with `underscore` but I suspect that is going to have a negative impact on performance.

PS: I also tried using similar approaches with the `find` call, no dice.

Comment: Never used Mongoose, but in pure Mongo shell, the following should resolve your problem
`db.characters.find( "this.currentHitPoints < this.maxHitPoints" )`

Comment: Indeed, it does! And it's so straightforward it would be very strange for Mongoose not to be able to do it!

Comment: Found an answer. Your suggestion was priceless, thanks!

Comment: On the top of my head, shouldn't something like `find({ 'status.currentHitpoints': { $lt: 'status.maximumHitpoints' } })` work?

Comment: Nope, I tried and that doesn't work, it gives the same error as using the `lt` method. But I found a solution and posted it below!

Comment: Glad I could help! Btw, just like a lot of other commenters on Stack Overflow, I just googled your question, read a few lines from the very well written documentation of MongoDB. Also, if you are serious about Mongo, I would also recommend reading the definitive guide book. Very well written!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Aniket's suggestion in the question's comments, I found that the same can be done with Mongoose using the following syntax:

```
mongoose.model('Character')
    .find({
        player: _currentPlayer
    })
    .$where('this.status.currentHitpoints < this.status.maximumHitpoints')
    .exec(callback)
```

Notice the `$where` method is used instead of the `where` method.

EDIT: To expand on [Derick's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2192473/derick-leony) comment below, a more performance sensitive solution would be to have a boolean property inside your Mongoose schema containing the result of the comparison, and update it everytime the document is saved. This can be easily achieved through the use of Mongoose Schema Plugin, so you would have something like:

```
var CharacterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // ...
    status: {
        hitpoints: Number,
        maxHitpoints: Number,
        isInFullHealth: {type: Boolean, default: false}
    }
})
.plugin(function(schema, options) {
     schema.pre('save', function(next) {
         this.status.isInFullHealth = (this.status.hitPoints >= this.status.maxHitpoints);

         next();
     })
 })
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that this kind of queries can get very slow for large collections because it doesn't use indexes. If performance is an issue, the solution is to have an auxiliar boolean property with the value of the comparisson.

Answer (score 12):

MongoDB 3.6 and above supports aggregation expressions within the query language:

```
db.monthlyBudget.find( { $expr: { $gt: [ "$spent" , "$budget" ] } } )
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/

Answer (score 1):

```
mongoose.model('Character')
    .find({
        player: _currentPlayer, $expr: { $lt: ['$currentHitpoints', '$maximumHitpoints'] }
    })
```

This above query means find the record which has `currentHitpoints` less than `maximumHitpoints`

Answer (score 1):

Starting in MongoDB 5.0, the $eq, $lt, $lte, $gt, and $gte comparison operators placed in an $expr operator can use an index on the from collection referenced in a $lookup stage.

**Example**
The following operation uses $expr to find documents where the spent amount exceeds the budget:

```
db.monthlyBudget.find( { $expr: { $gt: [ "$spent" , "$budget" ] } } )
```